# sum function return wrong value

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join

I have 4 tables in MySQL like this

First table: student

```
id    Name       roll      final
1     vivek      22222     65000
2     abc        33333     50000
```

Second table: discount

```
id    gst_amount   roll 
1     5000         22222
2     6500         22222
3     15000        22222
4     6000         33333
```

Third table: fee

```
id    amount       roll 
1     15000        22222
2     5000         22222
3     5000         33333
```

Fourth table: pdc

```
id    amount       roll 
1     9250         22222
2     9250         22222
```

I want to join all tables and want to sum of amount from `pdc` and `fee` table and sum of `gst_amount` from `discount` table and final column value.

I had tried this query.

```
SELECT student.roll, final, SUM(discount.gst_amount) AS total, SUM(fee.amount) AS fee, SUM(pdc.amount) AS pdc  
FROM student 
LEFT JOIN discount on student.roll = discount.roll 
LEFT JOIN fee on fee.roll = student.roll 
LEFT JOIN pdc on pdc.roll = student.roll 
GROUP BY student.roll
```

It's giving me this output.

```
roll      final     total     fee       pdc
22222     65000     106000    120000    110000
33333     50000     6000      5000      NULL
```

I want this output.

```
roll      final     total     fee       pdc
22222     65000     26000     20000     18500
33333     50000     6000      5000      NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original query is calculating duplicate sum values.
I think you can understand to add `count(1)` column to your original query.
The following is my output.

```
mysql> SELECT student.roll, count(1) as count
    -> FROM student
    -> LEFT JOIN discount on student.roll = discount.roll
    -> LEFT JOIN fee on fee.roll = student.roll
    -> LEFT JOIN pdc on pdc.roll = student.roll
    -> GROUP BY student.roll
    -> ;
+-------+-------+
| roll  | count |
+-------+-------+
| 22222 |    12 |
| 33333 |     1 |
+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Based on those, please run as below sql.
I think there are improvement point on this sql, but I have got your expected results for now.
Also 26000 in total column is wrong on your want output and 26500 is right, i think.

```
SELECT 
    student.roll,
    final,
    SUM(discount.gst_amount) AS total,
    SUM(fee.amount) AS fee,
    SUM(pdc.amount) AS pdc
FROM
    student
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        roll, SUM(gst_amount) AS gst_amount
    FROM
        discount
    GROUP BY roll) AS discount ON discount.roll = student.roll
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        roll, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        fee
    GROUP BY roll) AS fee ON fee.roll = student.roll
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        roll, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        pdc
    GROUP BY roll) AS pdc ON pdc.roll = student.roll
GROUP BY student.roll
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of why this works and the original query doesn't?

Comment: added explanation. I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry I don't give you a concrete anwser, but I am not the best in this. You could try and do it with sub-queries. This will get the sum of the gst_amount for each roll in the discount table:

```
SELECT roll, SUM(gst_amount) AS gst_amount
FROM discount 
GROUP BY roll
```

If you then implement it in your current query, then it might work.